# How to automate SQL queries to avoid manually executing it everytime

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a set of SQL queries that has some dynamic values in it. Every time I need to manually update those dynamic values and ask the DB team to run those SQL queries. For example, in the below set of SQL queries, values such as `1001`, `WASTE MANAGEMENT`, `WASTE MANAGEMENT_SUB`, `3846333` are dynamic values that need to be modified for a different set of values. I am looking for a way to write some stored procedures so that these values can be added dynamically and execute that procedure to insert into DB. I am basically a UI developer and new to automating `SQL` queries. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Any help or tips on any alternate solutions are appreciated. Any help on how to achieve my understanding is also highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_BILLERS values('1001','WASTE MANAGEMENT','WASTE MANAGEMENT','WASTE MANAGEMENT_SUB','3846333');

INSERT INTO TBL_FP_BILLER_HEADER(BILLER_NAME) 
SELECT UNIQUE(biller_name) 
FROM temp_billers 
WHERE cif IN ('3846333') 
ORDER BY biller_name asc;

INSERT INTO TBL_FP_BILLER_DETAIL(biller_id, cif, service_id, service_name, account_number) 
SELECT tblh.biller_id, tbltemp.cif, tbltemp.acc_num, tbltemp.service_name, tbltemp.acc_num 
FROM TBL_FP_BILLER_HEADER tblh
INNER JOIN TEMP_BILLERS tbltemp
    on tblh.biller_name=tbltemp.biller_name
where tbltemp.cif='3846333';

UPDATE TBL_FP_BILLER_DETAIL 
SET PAYMENT_TYPE='A'
    ,REF_RETENTION_POLICY='90'
    , REF_EXPIRATION_POLICY='7' 
WHERE CIF='';

Insert into TBL_FP_USER_DEFAULT_BILLER (BILLER_ID,BILLER_NAME,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY) 
select c.biller_id,'WASTE MANAGEMENT',null,null,null,null 
from TBL_FP_BILLER_DETAIL c 
where cif='3846333';
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be something like:

```
create procedure example (@ttt nvarchar(100), @ddd nvarchar(100) as 
BEGIN

insert into sometable
select something
where somecolumn = @ttt
END
```

You should create procedure that get required parameters, and then use them in your queries.

Comment: Can you please provide explanation of what is @ ttt @ ddd, sometable , something, somecolumn. I literally didnt understand anything

Comment: Sure, you should pass parameters to the stored procedure. Each parameters implicit defined in procedure definition name, type and in some types length. Name of parameters must start from "@" symbol. 
You can use inside the procedures this parameters when you need, in this question, it'll be used instead of hard coded values in INSERT/UPDATE statements
For more information please refer to [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6140/sql-server-stored-procedure-input-parameter-output-parameter-and-return-value/)